# Running out of memory in a for loop swift (4)

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, swift-structs

I'm looping through all pages in a PDFDocument (200+ pages) but app crashes with

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

The pdf is approx 4mb in size yet each iteration of the loop jumps the memory up approx 30mb. Which doesn't seem right to me. I have managed to locate where in my code the memory is being used just not sure how to claim it back. Tried setting variables to nil but no effect. Tried code in the for loop in an `autoreleaspool{}` but no effect.

```
@objc func scrapePDF(){

    let documentURL = self.documentDisplayWebView!.url!
    let document = PDFDocument(url: documentURL)
    let numberOfPages = document!.pageCount

    DispatchQueue.global().async {

        for pageNumber in 1...numberOfPages {

           print(document?.page(at: pageNumber)!.string!)

        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: solved ..... kind of

Playing around a bit I found that rather than passing a reference to the `PDFDocument` inside the loop, if instead I create a new instance for each loop this strangely solves the memory issue. I don't quite understand why though. `PDFDocument` is a Class not a Struct so is passed by reference. Meaning it is only created once and then referenced to inside my loop. So why would it cause a memory issue?

```
@objc func scrapePDF(){

    let documentURL = self.documentDisplayWebView!.url!
    let document = PDFDocument(url: documentURL)
    let numberOfPages = document!.pageCount

    DispatchQueue.global().async {

        for pageNumber in 1...numberOfPages {
           let doc = PDFDocument(url: documentURL)
           print(doc?.page(at: pageNumber)!.string!)

        }
    }
}
```

Though the above code clears the memory issue the problem with it is that its too slow. Each loop takes 0.5 seconds and with 300+ pages I can't accept that. Any tips on speeding it up? Or why it doesn't give the memory back if referencing the `PDFDocument` from outside the loop

Further UPDATE. 
 It seems that it’s calling the `.string` method of the `PDFPage` that is increases the memory to the point of crashing.

Comment: Hi - this question refers to creating PDF's and not reading them. however, the solution may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699194/memory-warning-and-crash-when-creating-pdf  <- It refers to running one page at a time.

Comment: Have you tried fetching the first 20 pages to see if the memory is released when the loop completes?

Comment: As per Apple docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument/1436036-string   String >`This is a convenience method, equivalent to creating a selection object for the entire document and then invoking the PDFSelection class’s string method.` Looks like it will create String representation of entire document and using  PDFSelection convince init it will get that one page so memory will is affecting here

Comment: @Laffen yeah if I do that I get significant portions of the memory back. I could write so logic to read n number of pages at a time but I’d rather not if avoidable

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya but that’s if I call string in the PDFDocument. When calling on the page it should return just the text of that page. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfpage/1503949-string

Comment: @RyanTCB oh I missed that , Did you tried with different PDF's ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I’ve tried numerous PDFs and as long as the document is less that 200 pages it can complete the loop and return the memory. However I can’t be sure of the size of the PDF so need a solution to reclaim memory. My option so far is to follow Laffen suggestion and fetch parts at a time. I’d rather understand why swift keeps it’s all I’m memory

Comment: what happens if you remove the line `DispatchQueue.global().async {`

Comment: @meggar it freezes the UI. Didn’t think it was good practice to do that

Comment: right but does it use the same memory?

Comment: @meggar yes. Sorry

Comment: It almost looks like that the `PDFDocument` caches the fetched pages, resulting in a memory warning when the cache gets to big. This explains why it works instantiating a new `PDFDocument` in every loop, because then only one page is cached at any given time.

I'm curious on why you're scraping the PDF in the first place?

Comment: Im scraping so I can enter details into a calendar rather than having user enter manually. I also conclude that its caching the fetched pages but why? Why is it not just using the instance passed in. If `PDFDocument` was a Struct id get that it sends copy but its a Class so by reference.